# Python minidom: Possible to avoid discarding metadata, whitespace?

Tags: python, xml

I am editing XML using python module `xml.dom.minidom`. The problem is the following. When i update my XML file using `writexml` it removes spaces from program and it also removes some data, for example it will automatically remove `standalone="yes"` from `<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>`.

Please help me to solve this problem. This is my code:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import xml.dom.minidom

file_handle = open(r'c:\users\g\desktop\filename.xml',"wb")
DOMTree = xml.dom.minidom.parse(r'c:\users\g\desktop\IT_ADMINVersionTrack.xml')
collection = DOMTree.documentElement
movies = collection.getElementsByTagName("dtModule")

for movie in movies:
   type2 = movie.getElementsByTagName('FolderName')[0]
   print "Folder: %s" % type2.childNodes[0].data
   type = movie.getElementsByTagName('Version')[0]
   print "VERSION: %s" % type.childNodes[0].data
   type = movie.getElementsByTagName('Version')[0]
   type.childNodes[0].data = "12.15.0"
   print "NEW VERSION: %s" % type.childNodes[0].data

DOMTree.writexml(file_handle)
```

Comment: Where is `standalone="yes"`?

Comment: Please edit your post to show the input and output XML and what you believe is wrong.

Comment: it is in my xml file input xml <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?> and out put xml is like <?xml version="1.0" ?> "standalone="yes" removed

Comment: Ahh -- so that's in the metadata, not the data. Not so surprising, that.

Comment: By the way -- why are you using minidom? It's there for compatibility with ancient code, but not a good choice for new development; newer XML libraries bundled with the Python runtime (xml.etree) or widely-used despite being unbundled (lxml.etree) supersede it.

Comment: I've edited your question to be a more descriptive -- when you say "error", that brings to mind a crash, as opposed to silently failing to round-trip metadata (which many libraries simply don't promise to do, making it not erroneous at all).